# How to parse a response from python requests method if the response is not in json format?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python request method for sending a Post API request.
The content of the response obtained is in the following format:

```
<RESPONSE>
<DATE></DATE>
<CODE></CODE>
</RESPONSE>
```

How to proceed in parsing the response if I want to get the code from the response?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like XML; parse it using an XML library?

Depending on the situation, you could also ignore that it's XML and just pluck out the pieces that you need; this will be particularly useful if the response is not in fact valid XML, but risks summoning [eldritch horrors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/683329).